# How to find out inside which loop Python is stuck?

Tags: python

I have a `.py` file that has a number of functions. Now I am debugging the codes and find that sometimes the program is stuck somewhere.

If I just leave it there and wait for a super long time, error message shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in generate
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in choosePath
MemoryError
```

I have **no idea where it is stuck**, as I have several `while` and `for` loops. Is there any easy way to figure out that *easily*? I feel really reluctant to debug one loop by another.

Comment: Give a `print` statement and use `break` or `exit` at possible places

Comment: @user567879  this is exactly what I am trying to avoid. :P

Comment: Thanks, glad I was of help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hit <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> and look at the traceback.

For example, the following code will hit a never-ending loop:

```
import time

def foo():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

def bar():
    for i in range(10):
        foo()

bar()
```

and when I interrupt it I see:

```
$ bin/python endless_demo.py 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    bar() 
  File "test.py", line 9, in bar
    foo()
  File "test.py", line 5, in foo
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The traceback ends in `foo`, on line 5. This is where Python was busy when I interrupted the program. The traceback also tells me that first `bar()` was called, which called `foo()`, so I can see how we got there.

Note that if you have a *bare* `except` handler this won't necessarily work; catching **all** exceptions with `try:` `except:` catches `KeyboardInterrupt` too. Always use [`except Exception:`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception) at a minimum to prevent catching system exceptions.

Comment: Awesome. Rapid and easy and effective. Thanks!

Comment: +1 I wondered how you obtained the image of CTRL-C in a cadre. I pressed on edit button and saw it is with the writing <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>. I read the help rubrique , advanced help page and even searched for kbd in the official Markdown syntax reference page whose link is given in the advanced help page. I found nowhere this information. Where did you learn it ?

Comment: @eyquem: [Hidden features of Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10662) and [How do I insert the images of keys in Stack Overflow or Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48939)

Comment: @eyquem: `<kbd>` is one of the [permitted HTML tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) in Stack Exchange Markdown.

Comment: In fact it is explained in the advanced help page but I didn't a CTRL-F search in this page, I just did it in the Markdown syntax reference page. And as I don't know 
HTML I didn't recognize the tag and my eye wasn't attracted by the word HTML in this advanced help page. Anyway,thank you very much, I now am aware of the very interesting 'Hidden Features' thread